# What does tilde(~) mean in ROS?

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this sample of code:

```
def ranger(channel, frame_id):
range_pub = rospy.Publisher('~', Range, queue_size=10)
rate = rospy.Rate(15)
```

and this sample

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('obstacle_sensor', anonymous=True)
    c = rospy.get_param('~channel')
    f = rospy.get_param('~frame_id')
    try:
        ranger(channel=c, frame_id=f)
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403556/what-does-tilde(%7E)-mean-in-ros?/) by [RoboTBiLL](https://answers.ros.org/users/77403/robotbill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-07-08**:
As it's already been answered we'll leave this open, but it's a duplicate of #q250092 (which has a *very* similar title: "Ask about the usage of the tilde '~'sign").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tilde means "local namespace" and will prefix your node name to the value after the tilde. So if your node was named "my_node" and you publish to "~topic" the actual topic name published will be "my_node/topic".

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2022-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboTBiLL](https://answers.ros.org/users/77403/robotbill/) on 2022-07-08**:
Thank you!